# Вставная конструкция или пояснение?

Tags: вставка

Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими властями — забирать деньги из накопительной пенсионной системы за 2015 год или нет, — не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России.
Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими властями — забирать деньги из накопительной пенсионной системы за 2015 год или нет, не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России.
Какой из этих вариантов правильные и почему?

Answer (score 3):

Вставная конструкция тоже может быть пояснением. Вы не совсем точно сформулировали вопрос. Вас интересует, вставная это конструкция или обособленное определение?

**Определения-инфинитивы** выделяются с помощью **тире**, а не запятой или двоеточия.
2) Если обособленное определение, выраженное инфинитивом, находится в середине предложения, то оно отделяется при помощи тире с двух сторон.

Каждый из них решал этот вопрос – уехать или остаться – для себя, для своих близких (Кетлинская).

**Но если по условиям контекста после определения должна стоять запятая, то второе тире обычно опускается.**

***Так как оставался один выбор – потерять армию и Москву или одну Москву, то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее (Л. Толстой).***  [Здесь](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_3_4)

В Вашем случае это **обособленное определение**, а не вставная конструкция. Второе тире по вышеизложенному правилу поглощается запятой. Но я бы его поставила, честно говоря, вместе с запятой, чтобы обособление было чётким, по всем правилам, с помощью двух тире. А запятая завершает придаточное предложение.

Правильными, на мой взгляд, являются оба варианта, но второй вариант предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 2):

Это пояснение. Перед поясняемом словом можно поставить "а именно". Конструкцию можно оформить двояко: с помощью двух тире, или при помощи двоеточия(чтобы избежать двух тире). 
Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими властями ***— забирать деньги из накопительной пенсионной системы за 2015 год или нет -***  не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России.

Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими ***властями:*** забирать деньги из накопительной пенсионной системы ***за 2015 год или нет -***  не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России.

Дополнение. Ответ справочной службы Грамма.ру

Предложение "Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими властями, — забирать деньги из накопительной
пенсионной системы за 2015 год или нет — не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России" может быть оформлен при помощи двойного тире. Данный случай подпадает под правило употребления обособленного определения, имеющего пояснительно-уточняющий характер и, таким образом, сближающегося с пояснительным членом предложения. См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 206-207, 223-224; Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по пунктуации. М., 1984. С. 56-57, 87-90. Единственное замечание, касающееся пунктуационного оформления этого примера, относится к месту запятой: она должна идти с первым тире, а не со вторым, так как поясняющее определение относится к слову "выбор".

Comment: В вашем примере перед первым тире обязательно должна стоять запятая, закрывающая придаточное, ибо конструкция относится к слову выборе перед придаточным.

Answer (score 2):

Это может быть и  вставной конструкцией (добавочным замечанием, разъясняющим, какой именно выбор), и  пояснением.

Пояснение выделяется чаще всего двумя запятыми, но у нас поясняющим членом является несогласованное определение в виде однородных членов, в таком случае перед ним ставится тире, а после него запятая, чтобы закрыть придаточное предложение.(здесь пунктуация как при  обособленном приложении в конце предложения, когда можно поставить ЭТО)

1.Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими властями — забирать деньги из накопительной пенсионной системы за 2015 год или нет,  не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России.

Если рассмотреть как вставную конструкцию, лучше обособить скобками, т.к. замечание резко выпадает из синтаксической структуры.

2.Некоторые аналитики видят в выборе, который сейчас встает перед российскими властями ( забирать деньги из накопительной пенсионной системы за 2015 год или нет), не просто вопрос определения наиболее успешной финансовой стратегии, но вопрос идеологического самоопределения России.

Comment: Да, такое оформление тоже возможно. Но оформление при помощи двух тире вполне оправдано здесь.

Comment: Людмила, вполне возможно и двоеточие.

Comment: Двоеточие возможно как авторский знак, два тире возможны, но нежелательны, потому что конструкция сложна и не очень сочетается с построением всего предложения, скобки вносят чёткость в понимание смысла и структуры.

Comment: У Розенталя говорится, что двоеточие ставится, чтобы избежать двух тире.

Comment: А вы не считаете, что в случае постановки тире перед первым из них обязательно должна стоять запятая, закрывающая придаточное, ибо конструкция относится к слову выборе перед придаточным?

Comment: Согласна, запятая нужна